# UITableViewCell, динамически меняющая высоту в заисимости от динамического размера UIView внутри нее

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Сразу объясню, что использую `autolayout`, `UITableViewController` и в `viewWillAppear(bool)` указываю следующее

```
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000
```

суть в том, что в ячейке которую необходимо растягивать находится View, размеры которого определяются в `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, а именно

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TagViewCell", 
forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TagViewCell
cell.configure(product.tags)
```

функция configure получает массив строк и на основовании его заполняет `UIView`, который я назову `TagHolder` (по сути просто пустой `UIView`) другими однотипными view, которые я назвал `TagView`. По клику на них юзер будет получать нужную информацию и переходить по страницам. Логика такая, что обычно теги не помещаются в одну строку, например это может выглядеть так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а могут занять и три строки, ну или если их мало - одну, а следовательно высота `TagHolder'а` меняется, и меняется уже после того, как ячейка отрисована (после вызова `awakeFromNib`) и ее размер в `UITableView` остается таким, как был нарисован в `MainStoryboard`.

Есть ли способ сконфигурировать `TagHolder` перед тем, как iOS будет вычислять размеры ячейки?

UPDATE:

Autolayout я использую именно потому что на странице несколько разнотипных ячеек и некоторые из них содержат динамические view, например product decription cell содержит UITextView, величина которого разная для каждого продукта, а конфигурируется тем не менее после

```
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
```

значит я возможно неправильно осуществляю динамическое изменение TagHolder'а

```
class TagHolder: UIView {

    override var width: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            reload()
        }
    }

    var stringTags : [Tag] = []
    var tags : [TagView] = []

    var lines : CGFloat = 1 {
        willSet {
            let tag = TagView.create(0, y: 0, tag: Tag(name: "i", id: "0", id1c: "0"))
            self.height = newValue * tag.height
        }
    }
    var curx : CGFloat = 0
    var cury : CGFloat = 0 {
        willSet {
            if newValue > cury { lines += 1 }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
    }

    func reload() {
        let stags = stringTags
        stringTags = []
        tags = []
        for tag in self.tags {
            tag.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.add(stags)
    }

    @nonobjc func add(tags : [Tag]) {
        self.stringTags += tags
        for tagstring in tags {
            var tag = TagView.create(curx, y: cury, tag : tagstring)

            let inline = curx + tag.width <= screenWidth
            curx = inline ? curx + tag.width : 0
            cury = inline ? cury : cury + tag.height
            tag = inline ? tag : TagView.create(curx, y: cury, tag : tagstring)
            self.addSubview(tag)
            self.tags.append(tag)
            curx = inline ? curx : curx + tag.width
        }
    }

    @nonobjc func add(tag : Tag) {
        let a : [Tag] = [tag]
        self.add(a)
    }
}
```

self.height определено в extension для UIView

```
var height:CGFloat {
    get {
        return self.frame.size.height
    }
    set {
        self.frame.size.height = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded() не помогает?

Comment: хм, не помогло визуально, но тем не менее после layout if needed я вывел в консоль высоту contentView и tagHolder и они оказались верными (высота tagView соответствует количеству тэгов, а высота contentView равна высоте tagView + margins), т.е. все пересчиталось, но не перерисовалось

Comment: Могу только отослать к Рэю, у него неплохой пример есть, где всё работает: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Пример замечательный, но у него используются нативные view, а у меня похоже загвоздка в том, что view кастомное. Похоже чего то я не учел

Comment: У него ещё используется связка  `tableView.beginUpdates()` `tableView.endUpdates()` после `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded` возможно это инициирует перерисовку.

Comment: In addition to the constraint changes, the table view needs to refresh the cell heights now. Calling beginUpdates() and endUpdates() will force the table view to refresh the heights in an animated fashion.

Comment: Все не так просто, в этой статье все происходит по клику - что то вроде разворачивания ячкейки, мне же надо показывать ее срзу. А если я помещаю эти методы в cellForRowAtIndexPath, то перерисовка страницы (полностью) происходит каждый раз, когда я долистываю до ячейки с тэгами. Но направление хорошее, попробую покопать в нем, спасибо

Comment: Чем мог. Будет очень полезно, если Вы расскажете в финале, как Вам удалось разобраться с данной проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри ячейки все constraints должны быть по высоте жестко стоять, тогда добавьте две строки в viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я указал в самом начале вопроса, что сделал это

Answer (score 1):

Если таких ячеек не много, то можешь создать их ручками (в viewDidLoad, например), заполнить TagHolder и передавать в методах делегата и ячейку, и ее размер.

Тайкже можешь изменить метод cell.configure так, чтоб он мог только вычислять размер. Соответсвенно, в heightForRowAtIndexPath возвращаешь размер, в cellForRowAtIndexPath - заполняешь ячейку.

Comment: Хм, только что полумал. Я использую autolayout именно потому то у меня много разных типов ячеек и в некоторых размер контента может быть разный, например product decription различается по высоте для каждого из продуктов. А конфигурируется между тем после того, как произошел dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, но тем не менее визуально это выглядит прекрасно (там UITextView). А отсяда вопрос - правильно ли я меняю высоту TagHolder и как вообще нужно это делать?

Comment: Сложно сказать тк не видно как ты меняешь высоту. Попробуй это вообще убрать и проверить. По идеи, вью должна растягиваться под свои сабвью. По дефолту.

Comment: Апдейт в теле вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Возможно мое решение было не идеальным, но я поступил следующим образом:

добавил в класс TagHolder

```
var tagHolderHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
```

в инициализатор TagHolder

```
tagHolderHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: size)
```

в метод add у класса TagHolder

```
self.tagHolderHeightConstraint?.constant = self.height
```

после чего высота ячейки стала расчитываться абсолютно корректно

Answer (score 0):

Вот подробное описание: [Автоматический размер ячейки UITableView, или немоного про UITableViewAutomaticDimension](https://proswift.ru/avtomaticheskij-razmer-yachejki-uitableview-ili-nemonogo-pro-uitableviewautomaticdimension/), и ссылка на  GitHub: [UITableViewAutomaticDimension](https://github.com/Ironrnd/UITableViewAutomaticDimension).